# How to upload a resized image in Google cloud Storage?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

How to upload an image file in Google Cloud Storage that I already resized using 3rd party package `"github.com/disintegration/imaging"`?

I tried this

**Code:**

```
f, uploadedFile, err := c.Request.FormFile("file") // image file
    // Decode the file into a image struct
     srcImg, _, err:=  image.Decode(f)

    // Resize srcImage to width = 800px preserving the aspect ratio.
    adjustedFile := imaging.Resize(srcImg, 800, 0, imaging.Lanczos)

    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "message": err.Error(),
            "error":   true,
        })
        return
    }

    defer f.Close()

    sw := storageClient.Bucket(bucket).Object(""+ callType +"/"+ yearString +"/"+ monthString +"/" + uploadedFile.Filename).NewWriter(ctx)
    
    if _, err := io.Copy(sw, adjustedFile); err != nil { // error here
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "message": err.Error(),
            "error":   true,
        })
        return
    }
```

**Error:**

```
`cannot use adjustedFile (type *image.NRGBA) as type io.Reader in a`rgument to io.Copy:
    *image.NRGBA does not implement io.Reader (missing Read method)
```

Comment: Use the [image/jpeg](https://godoc.org/image/jpeg#Encode) package to encode the image to bytes: `err := jpeg.Encode(sw, adjustedFile, &jpeg.Options{Quality:77})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as a community wiki, since It's based on @CeriseLimon's comment.

The problem is that you have to encode your image to bytes before sending it to GCS and you can do it by using the [image/jpeg](https://godoc.org/image/jpeg#Encode) package, try the following code

```
if _, err := jpeg.Encode(sw, adjustedFile, &jpeg.Options{Quality:77}); err != nil {
    ...
}
```